# Obtaining only the filename when using OpenFileDialog property "FileName"

Tags: c#, .net, filenames, openfiledialog

I am trying to include only the filename of the file I've selected in the OpenFileDialog in the label1.Text property, but I haven't found a solution yet.
I know I could use a method from the string class on the ofd instance to filter out the whole path to the file, but I would like to know if a smarter/quicker way exists?

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
ofd.Title = "Find song";
ofd.Filter = "MP3 files|*.mp3";
ofd.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   label1.Text = "" + ofd.FileName +"";
}
```

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Use [OpenFileDialog.SafeFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.safefilename.aspx)

`OpenFileDialog.SafeFileName` Gets the file name and extension for the file selected in the dialog box. The file name does not include the path.

Comment: if i need only name with out extension then ?

Comment: @rahularyansharma, you can get by this `System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(OpenFileDialog.FileName)`

Answer (score 34):

Use: [Path.GetFileName Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx)

```
var onlyFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(ofd.FileName);
```